# Auto Login to Telnet Server using C#

Tags: c#

I want to auto log into out telnet server by creating a windows service program.
Can I use putty or something similar?

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a TCP socket and connect it to port 23.

Assuming you don't need any specific type of terminal emulation, you are now talking to the telnet server and you can send and receive information.

If you can provide more details on what you are trying to accomplish perhaps we can be of more help.